# Coupling memory pool allocator to various memory pools hosting the allocated instances

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, allocator, memory-pool

There is an stateless memory pool allocator class:

```
template<typename T>
class pool_allocator {
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using pointer = value_type *;

    /* Default constructor */
    constexpr pool_allocator( void ) noexcept = default;

    /* Converting constructor used for rebinding */
    template<typename U>
    constexpr pool_allocator( const pool_allocator<U> & ) noexcept {}

    [[nodiscard]] pointer allocate( size_t n, [[maybe_unused]] const pointer hint = nullptr ) const noexcept {
        return get_pool().allocate( n );
    }

    void deallocate( pointer ptr, size_t n ) const noexcept {
        get_pool().deallocate( ptr, n );
    }

private:
    /* Must be defined in particular .cpp files */
    /* POINT OF INTERREST HERE: */
    static auto & get_pool( void ) noexcept;
};
```

The logic behind is there is the specialization of `get_pool()` member function which is intended to return particular memory pool of defined type where the instance of T shall be allocated, for example:

```
class sample { ... };
```

in .cpp file:

```
memory_pool<sample, 10> sample_storage;  // memory pool capable of holding up to 10 instances of 'sample'
```

finally there comes the specialization of get_pool() function template in .cpp file:

```
template<>
auto & pool_allocator<sample>::get_pool( void ) noexcept {
    return sample_storage; // return the memory_pool instance defined above
}
```

The problem is such template specialization is available only in .cpp compilation unit and prevents the usage of `auto get_pool()` in other compilation unit ( the type of `auto` placeholder cannot be deduced as the body of `get_pool()` function template specialization is not available )

> There fore I would like to somehow get rid of `auto` as return type
> of `get_pool()`.

The problem I face is mainly with the size of the `memory_pool` which is unknown to the allocator itself. Anyway, the memory_pool is also my implementation so I can du whatever adoptions required (e.g. further `using` declarations or whatever else is needed). Just a skeleton of it:

```
template<typename T, size_t CAPACITY>
class memory_pool {
public:
    using element_type = T;
    using pointer = element_type *;

    constexpr size_t capacity( void ) noexcept {
        return CAPACITY;
    }
...
};
```

Comment: `get_pool` returns an object of some kind of type that has `allocate` and `deallocate` member functions. Do you know what that type is? If yes, just specify it instead of `auto`. If not, why are you so sure that it has `allocate` and `deallocate` with just the right signatures? Perhaps you can derive that fact from some other assumptions, what are they?

Comment: In general, `pool_allocator` shall be stateless. On the other hand, shall allocate the instances in some dedicated memory area managed by the `memory_pool`. For any particular type, there is a specialization of `pool_allocator` template and shall exist an instance of a `memory_pool` of particular size. But how to tell the allocator in which pool to allocate? That is what the get_pool shall serve for. But how to handle the size to be known to `pool_allocator` template in order to use the correct pool type for instance `memory_pool<sample, 10> & get_pool( void )` where the '10' is the issue?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, `get_pool` wants to return some kind of `memory_pool`, but it is not known which exact kind at the point of use. So C++ has a mechanism for that. It is centered around inheritance and virtual functions, and is called "object orientation".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I used - to implement the traits class which holds the information about the pool size:

```
template<typename T>
class memory_pool {
public:
    using traits = memory_pool_traits<T>;
    using element_type = typename traits::element_type;
    using pointer = element_type *;

    static constexpr size_t capacity { traits::capacity };
...
};
```

The allocator:

```
template<typename T>
class pool_allocator {
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using pointer = value_type *;

    /* Default constructor */
    constexpr pool_allocator( void ) noexcept = default;

    /* Converting constructor used for rebinding */
    template<typename U>
    constexpr pool_allocator( const pool_allocator<U> & ) noexcept {}

    [[nodiscard]] pointer allocate( size_t n, [[maybe_unused]] const pointer hint = nullptr ) const noexcept {
        return get_pool().allocate( n );
    }

    void deallocate( pointer ptr, size_t n ) const noexcept {
        get_pool().deallocate( ptr, n );
    }

private:
    static memory_pool<T> & get_pool( void ) noexcept;
};
```

For any particular type there shall be traits class:

```
// Primary template
template<typename T> struct memory_pool_traits;
```

Let there be the sample for which I would like to define the `memory_pool`:

```
class sample { ... };
```

...and aside of that the setup - the traits - for the respective `memory_pool`:

```
template<>
struct memory_pool_traits<sample> {
    using element_type = sample;
    static constexpr size_t capacity { 10 };
};
```

In the `.cpp` file there is the definition of the pool itself and the `get_pool()` function:

```
memory_pool<sample> sample_storage;

template<>
memory_pool<sample> & pool_allocator<sample>::get_pool( void ) noexcept {
    return sample_storage;
}
```